# Polynomial functions as matrix elements

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra, matrix-multiplication, finite-element-analysis

Matrix `N` is a 2x2 matrix that contains polynomial functions:

```
N=[(1-x).*(1-y), 0 ;
   0 , (1-x).*(1-y)  ];
```

where `x` and `y` are defined over the interval `[0:1]` to make a square element

I also have an operator matrix, `D`

```
D= [d/dx, 0
    0, d/dy];
```

I want to evaluate the integral of:

```
int(D*B)dA
```

So my problem is, I can not define `x` and `y` as:

```
x= 0:dx:1
y= 0:dy:1
```

because then I would be storing vectors of `length(0:dx:1)` within the matrices as elements and the matrix multiplication would not work out due to improper dimensions.

So what is the best way to store these polynomials as function elements and then differentiate them with a matrix differentiation operator `D`

Comment: Are you actual matrices *2*-by-*2*? The best way is to probably just multiply them out yourself. It's only going to result in 2 equations right?

Comment: Can't you just use anonymous functions? `N=@(x,y) [(1-x).*(1-y), 0; 0 , (1-x).*(1-y)  ];`

Comment: @Dan they are quite large, actually! I want to avoid doing things by hand.

Comment: @RobertStettler I will look into that, that could work. I will update question if I need to. Thanks